# What is "riffing" on information security terms;

Tags: security

What is "riffing" on information security terms; I found this "riffing on threats" on a paper and i don't know what it exactly means

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like rare usage of the term in this context, whereas in more common contexts:

- He stole that riff from another song.
- a mock news program with humorous riffs on current events

These uses suggests "riff" could be interpreted as a variation, or spontaneous improvisation, of an idea.

An online dictionary defines "riff" as

> a distinct variation :  take (Example: "a disturbing … riff on the Cinderella story") [reference: Meriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/riff)

However, the term appears in technology context in a security handbook -

> "The book is there, like a riff in a popular sing, to catch the
>   recipient's interest and consists of an eye-catching tag such as "Tree
>   trainers!" or "Virus alert" and perhaps some expansion of the theme.
>   It exploits some basic psychological issue such as greed and
>   self-interest, fear of technology and its consequences, or sympathy
>   with the unfortunate. A threat inherent in this message pressures the
>   recipient into passing on the message. [Handbook of Information Security, Threats, Vulnerabilities, Prevention by Hossein Bidgoli](https://www.amazon.co.uk/d/Books/Handbook-Information-Security-Vulnerabilities-Prevention-Detection-Management/0470051213); [Google Books Text](https://books.google.com/books?id=0RfANAwOUdIC&pg=PA47&lpg=PA47&dq=riff+on+threats+security&source=bl&ots=pGTm1qp1sk&sig=SyUE1BUm3sdzyqCz9DQPbt1xYEY&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwibxo-mxb3TAhWrrFQKHXl_BZEQ6AEIRDAG#v=onepage&q=riff%20on%20threats%20security&f=false)

**TLDR;

Answer**: So, incorporating these definitions and examples into context of security, "riffing on threats" can be interpreted as **creating a variety of different security** threats.

---

Footnote:
On further reconsideration, this question (and a likely better answer) may be better suited for [English Language & Usage Stack Exchange](http://english.stackexchange.com).